# vbscript .DateCreated not coping with new month

Tags: vbscript

I'm using the following code to find the newest .zip file in a directory but it doesn't seem to be coping with the switch to June and still shows the newest file as yesterdays.

When I ran the script today it showed a file from 31/05/2011 06:05 as the latest but there are two newer files than this (see screenshot)

```
For Each aFile In ImportFldr.Files
sExtension = fso.GetExtensionName(aFile.Name)
    If sExtension = "log" Then
            'Msgbox "The file extension is a " & sExtension
        Else
            'Msgbox "The file extension is a " & sExtension
                         If fileNewest = "" Then
                        Set fileNewest = aFile  
                     Else
                     If fileNewest.DateCreated < aFile.DateCreated Then
                            Set fileNewest = aFile
                     End If
                    End If
                End If
Next
```

[image: screenshot of the directory showing files and there timestamps]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may be that you are checking the file creation date ([`DateCreated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke6a7czx.aspx)) whereas Explorer shows the last modification date ([`DateLastModified`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8xh895w.aspx)). Add the *Date created* column to the Explorer's view and see if the script's result makes sense after that.